# Definition adjectives for clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, definitions

For a school project, I need to explain which clustering algorithm of Scikit-Learn we need to use based on the input data.

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) is very well done, especially thanks to a comparative table of algos, but I have trouble understanding some adjectives. I would very much appreciate some definitions for the following terms :

```
Flat / non-flat geometry
Even / non-even cluster size
Inductive / Transductive
```

In addition, does "Not scalable" mean that the algorithm is not efficient when there is a lot of data?

Comment: There may be some helpful terms in the [SciKit-Learn Glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html).